# Py2 - Run Bash Script with Arguments - Store Output in a file in a different directory

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7

My code:

```py
for host in hostlist_split:
    path = currentDIR + "/" + scriptRESULTS + runtimeSCRIPT
    if os.path.exists(path):
        print 'Executing Script...'
        subprocess.check_call(['path', 'username', 'password'])
        print(stdout)
        sitesProcessed += 1
```

Script reads list of hosts from a file, iterates through them running another script on that host passing the required arguments for it to run, and then should ideally store the output of that subscript in a new file.

I'll name the file after the host the script ran on and store it in a directory named after the subscript.

Problem is I'm getting the message `no such file or directory` when executing this code.

1. I've verified the host is being read correctly and is stored in the list as a string.
2. I've verified the path to the subscript, the username, and the password are all being stored and supplied as expected.

But when using the `check_call` function the script will not run, and the stdout is not printed.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./pywrapper.py", line 136, in <module>
    subprocess.check_call(['path', 'username', 'password'])
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 537, in check_call
    retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 524, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: Just a quick check:  your first sample has a variable called `path`, but your traceback shows a literal string `'path'`.  Those are very different things.

Comment: Haha, you're right, i supplied path as a string instead of a variable. I did correct it but now i'm getting [Error 13] Permission Denied lol - And to be clear i have run chmod 777 * and dos2unix

Comment: Do you have a proper shebang line on line 1, like `#! /bin/bash` to tell the kernel what to execute?

Comment: Yes, i do. That wasn't the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

My script wasn't expanding the variables it was just reading them as strings.
I just switched from BASH so figuring out how to combine strings and variables in single line without adding spaces took me a while.

This is what I'm running now..

```
for host in hostlist_split:
    path = currentDIR + '/' + scriptRESULTS + runtimeSCRIPT

    if os.path.exists(path):
        print 'Executing Script...'
        sshARGS =  ('{}/{} {} {} {} > {}/{}'.format(currentDIR, runtimeSCRIPT, host, username, password, path, host) ) 
        SSH = subprocess.Popen(sshARGS, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        out, err = SSH.communicate()
        SSH.wait()
        sitesProcessed += 1
```